# Passar valor com desconto para PagSeguro

Tags: php

Estou desenvolvendo um carrinho de compra que ao valor atingir determinada faixa ele calcula um desconto para o cliente, calculo o frete e o valor do frete é somado  corretamente ao valor com desconto, mas percebi que ao finalizar o pedido e passar os valores para o `PagSeguro` o valor vai sem os descontos, passo para eles o que me é solicitado, dessa forma:

```
if ($TPFrete == 3){
    $peso = 0;
    $paymentRequest->addItem($cod_prod, $nome_prod, $quantidade_prod, $vlr, $peso);
} else {
    $paymentRequest->addItem($cod_prod, $nome_prod, $quantidade_prod, $vlr, $peso, $VLRFrete);
}
```

Creio que na página do `PagSeguro` ele calcula a quantidade x valor e ai o desconto não aparece, existe alguma forma de passar o valor desse desconto ao PagSeguro?
Vi que tem uma opção na documentação que possibilita calcular desconto, isso aqui:

```
$paymentRequest->setExtraAmount
```

Mas já estou com o valor calculado antes de passar para eles, existe alguma dica?
O atendimento do PagSeguro não me retornou as minhas perguntas, por isso esse post aqui, creio ser até mais rápido.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use o método:

```
setExtraAmount()
```

passando um valor negativo no parâmetro.
Exemplo:

```
$boleto->setExtraAmount(-10.00);
```

Desta forma ele acrescentará automaticamente o desconto ao total do carrinho do valor que ele envia para o pagseguro.
Caso já tenha o valor calculado, apenas multiplique por (-1) antes de passá-lo no parâmetro.

```
$desconto = 10.00;
$desconto_n = $desconto*(-1);
$boleto->setExtraAmount($desconto_n);
```

Answer (score 1):

Veja na documentação do [PAGSEGURO](https://pagseguro.uol.com.br/v2/guia-de-integracao/documentacao-da-biblioteca-pagseguro-em-php.html#!rmcl),
Você pode definir percentuais de descontos a serem oferecidos com base no meio de pagamento escolhido pelo seu cliente, durante o checkout, no ambiente do PagSeguro.

```
$paymentRequest->addPaymentMethodConfig('CREDIT_CARD', 1.00, 'DISCOUNT_PERCENT');  
$paymentRequest->addPaymentMethodConfig('EFT', 2.90, 'DISCOUNT_PERCENT');  
$paymentRequest->addPaymentMethodConfig('BOLETO', 10.00, 'DISCOUNT_PERCENT');  
$paymentRequest->addPaymentMethodConfig('DEPOSIT', 3.45, 'DISCOUNT_PERCENT');  
$paymentRequest->addPaymentMethodConfig('BALANCE', 0.01, 'DISCOUNT_PERCENT');
```

Comment: Olá @Eduardo, valeu pela dica, já tinha lido a documentação, mas como disse no post, já tenho o valor do desconto calculado, gostaria de mandar ele e não calcular